# Is there a straightforward way to specifically position bootstrap elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to position bootstrap elements - buttons or other, at a given horizontal start position on my page. The exact horizontal position should vary dynamically. It seems html (and to some extent bootstrap) wasn't exactly cut out for this but is there a good way to reliably accomplish that?

My best shot is fiddling with its horizontal margin. Is there something even more straightforward, that will bypass the need to consider all other elements in its column and can directly use the desired height regardless of what's else in the column?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific than that. Based on what input should the horizontal position be calculated? Also, are you aware on how the grid system works in bootstrap? (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Yes, aware, but in all sincerity would rather only use the components not the layout if I can. The input derives from user interaction. This question assumes the input height is an arbitrary value that is only determined and set by javascript at runtime.